# Using itoa with a TCHAR

Tags: c++, winapi, encoding

I have a Win32 C++ Application which supports UNICODE. I have a problem where I am using the itoa() function but I get a compile error because I am passing a TCHAR* as the parameter instead of a char*.

What can I do to make it work?

```
TCHAR buf[32];
itoa( taskState, buf, 10 );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no good reason to us `TCHAR` unless you're targeting Windows 9x with MFC in DLL, and you're sort of afraid to rebuild MFC. Just use `wchar_t`.

Then read  Microsoft's documentation of `itoa`.

There you find at least one variant that you can use with a `wchar_t` string.

It's generally not a good idea to use `itoa` family, but you're at the stage where you have not yet learned to look up the documentation.

So, that's what you should do: check the documentation (and yes, I have checked, and it is there).

---

Addendum, as of April 2015: Since mid 2011 we've had the C++11 and C++14 standards ratified, and compilers now commonly support the C++11 [`std::towstring`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_wstring) function from the `<string>` header; it's just as convenient as `itoa` and more safe.

Comment: I think there's something fundamentally wrong with SO when it protests that an answer consisting of the four letters RTFM is too short.

Comment: I can relate to that "too short answers" sometimes its very annoying because the answer can't be any bigger.

Comment: If everyone RTFM and understood it there would no need for sites like StackOverflow. Often the FM is badly written or so bloated that you can't see what you are looking for hidden in pages of techno-speak. Thank you StackOverflow for saving us from bad FM.

Answer (score 8):

For TCHAR strings you should use _ttoi().

Answer (score 3):

As Adam Pierce mentioned, the TCHAR version of _itoa() is _itot(), you will find it here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yakksftt(v=vs.80).aspx